Should I flip (negate) anticorrelated variables in hierarchical clustering?
In hierarchical clustering, I have one variable that seems to be coded the opposite direction to the others. It has a negative correlation with a majority of the other variables. (eg var 3 below)

I want to find which variables relate best to each other. The directions are arbitrary and irrelevant to the scientific question.  Two questions:

Do I need to flip (i.e. negate) a variable that is obviously negatively coded, to prevent it from becoming a separate cluster?
If we don't know whether variables are flipped, is there a rule for when to flip them? for example, "flip variable i if $r_{i,j}<0$  for more than 50% of its correlations with the other variables"?

